# fatal: ambiguous argument '–hard': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Tags: git-reset

I am trying to execute the below git commnand:

`git reset –hard DI_BINARY_REPOSITORY_IMX6_LINUX_14.4C504.2`

but I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '–hard': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You are using the wrong character for options. "–" != "--"

Comment: I tried using "--" still am  getting error like "Cannot do hard reset with paths".

Answer (score 2):

Here is my situation. I got same error when trying to return to very old commit. I found out that my local repo did not contains this commit. Adding param **depth=num_of_commits_to_fetch** resolves issue. Example:

```
git pull --depth=1000
git reset --hard 9e766b9
```

Answer (score 1):

Feth remote repo details first by below command.

```
 git fetch --all
```

Then hit below command
git reset **--**hard DI_BINARY_REPOSITORY_IMX6_LINUX_14.4C504.2

Answer (score 0):

two possibilities:

Are you passing the right parameter after hard? You need to specify which commit tag to reset to. HEAD and HEAD~1 (One commit before HEAD) are common.

Is that one dash or two you have with hard? It should be 2.

Comment: I tried using "--" still am getting error like "Cannot do hard reset with paths"

Comment: What do you put after the --hard? It does not take the file to reset, it takes a commit id, then it reverts all files to how they looked at that commit id. If you want to reset a single file you should try the checkout command: git checkout -- <path to file> which will reset the file to the most recent checked in version.